# Using Object.create for inheritance?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

This code is from the MDN article on `Object.create()`:

```
// Shape - superclass
function Shape() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
}

// superclass method
Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
  this.x += x;
  this.y += y;
  console.info('Shape moved.');
};

// Rectangle - subclass
function Rectangle() {
  Shape.call(this); // call super constructor.
}

// subclass extends superclass
Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;

var rect = new Rectangle();
```

The third to last line is the one that I'm confused about.

What would be the difference between:

A. how it is now.
B. `Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape);`
C. `Rectangle.prototype = new Shape();`

Wouldn't all 3 ultimately yield the same result? The same attributes defined on `rect` and the same use of memory to define them?

**Yes**, I have read the other StackOverflow questions addressing `Object.create()`. **No**, they did not fully address my confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `Object.create(Shape)` returns an object which inherits from `Shape`.

  If you want to make a subclass of `Shape`, you probably don't want to do this.
- `Object.create(Shape.prototype)` returns an object which inherits from `Shape.prototype`.

  Therefore, this object will not have the `x` and `y` own properties.
- `new Shape()` does this:

  1. Creates an object which inherits from `Shape.prototype`.
  2. Calls `Shape`, passing the previous object as `this`.
  3. Returns that object (assuming `Shape` didn't return another object).

  Therefore, this object will have the `x` and `y` own properties.

Comment: You probably should mention that one *doesn't want* the prototype object to have own `x` and `y` properties…

Comment: I just don't understand what happens when you call `Object.create(Shape)`. I get that it doesn't work but I don't know why. If you take out the line `Shape.call(this)` and use `Object.create(Shape)` instead of `Object.create(Shape.prototype)`, then instantiate a `Rectangle`, the resulting object has neither `x` nor `y` nor `move`. So what happened? What is being set as what?

Comment: @Aerovistae The problem is that, since `Shape` is a function, `Object.create(Shape)` inherits from `Shape` (which has no own property), `Function.prototype`, and `Object.prototype`. However, you are trying to subclass `Shape`. That means you want to inherit from `Shape.prototype` (which has the `move` method), and `Object.prototype`.